# How to make two Kubernetes Services talk to each other?

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, kubectl

Currently, I have working K8s API pods in a K8s service that connects to a K8s Redis service, with K8s pods of it's own. The problem is, I am using NodePort meaning BOTH are exposed to the public. I only want the API accessable to the public. The issue is that if I make the Redis service not public, the API can't see it. Is there a way to connect two Services without exposing one to the public?

This is my API service yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: app-api-svc
spec:
   selector:
     app: app-api
     tier: api
   ports:
     - protocol: TCP
       port: 5000
       nodePort: 30400
   type: NodePort
```

And this is my Redis service yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: app-api-redis-svc
spec:
   selector:
     app: app-api-redis
     tier: celery_broker
   ports:
     - protocol: TCP
       port: 6379
       nodePort: 30537
   type: NodePort
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First, configure the Redis service as a `ClusterIP` service. It will be private, visible only for other services. This is could be done removing the line with the option `type`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: app-api-redis-svc
spec:
   selector:
     app: app-api-redis
     tier: celery_broker
   ports:
     - protocol: TCP
       port: 6379
       targetPort: [the port exposed by the Redis pod]
```

Finally, when you configure the API to reach Redis, the address should be `app-api-redis-svc:6379`

And that's all. I have a lot of services communicating each other in this way. If this doesn't work for you, let me know in the comments.

Comment: I do need one service to be NodePort, that way the public or someone on a different computer can hit it. That is how it works right? I'm pretty slow when it comes to networking

Comment: The Redis service should be ClusterIP if you want it to be private. The API could be NodePort or LoadBalancer, that's okay.

Comment: How does the app resolve `app-api-redis-svc` to the cluster IP?

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to try to take the best from all answers and my own research and make a short guide that I hope you will find helpful:

## 1. Test connectivity

Connect to a different pod, eg ruby pod:

```
kubectl exec -it some-pod-name -- /bin/sh
```

Verify it can ping to the service in question:

```
ping redis
```

Can it connect to the port? (I found telnet did not work for this)

```
nc -zv redis 6379
```

## 2. Verify your service selectors are correct

If your service config looks like this:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    app: redis
    role: master
    tier: backend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
  selector:
    app: redis
    role: master
    tier: backend
```

verify those selectors are also set on your pods?

```
get pods --selector=app=redis,role=master,tier=backend
```

Confirm that your service is tied to your pods by running:

```
$> describe service redis
Name:           redis
Namespace:      default
Labels:         app=redis
            role=master
            tier=backend
Annotations:        <none>
Selector:       app=redis,role=master,tier=backend
Type:           ClusterIP
IP:         10.47.250.121
Port:           <unset> 6379/TCP
Endpoints:      10.44.0.16:6379
Session Affinity:   None
Events:         <none>
```

check the `Endpoints:` field and confirm it's not blank

More info can be found at:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#my-service-is-missing-endpoints

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about redis, but I have a similar application. I have a Java web application running as a pod that is exposed to the outside world through a nodePort. I have a mongodb container running as a pod.

In the webapp deployment specifications, I map it to the mongodb service through its name by passing the service name as parameter, I have pasted the specification below. You can modify accordingly.There should be a similar mapping parameter in Redis also where you would have to use the service name which is "mongoservice" in my case.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: empappdepl
    labels:
      name: empapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: empapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 0.2
            image: registryip:5000/employee:1
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            name: wsemp
            ports:
              - containerPort: 8080
                name: wsemp
            command: ["java","-Dspring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongoservice/microservices", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
        imagePullSecrets:
        - name: myregistrykey
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: empwhatever
  name: empservice
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
    nodePort: 30062
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    name: empapp
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodbdepl
  labels:
    name: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: mongodb
spec:
  containers:
  - resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 0.3
    image: mongo
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: mongodb
    ports:
    - containerPort: 27017
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: mongowhatever
  name: mongoservice
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    name: mongodb
```

Note that the mongodb service doesnt need to be exposed as a NodePort.

Comment: Don't you have the mongo service exposed in this example? The service is grabbing `mongodb` and it is the one with the NodePort. Am I right in saying that?

Comment: Yes, the mongo service is exposed, thats why I mentioned as a note that it need not be exposed as a node port. I'm not using it but havent bothered to remove it out of my poc. The flow is like this. Request from external world --> emp web service --> connects to mongodb internally and stores data.

Comment: How is the outside world able to hit the emp web service? Isn't it `ClusterIP` at the moment?

Comment: I hadn't pasted the emp service specifications earlier, now I have updated it. It is exposed through nodePort, mongodb will be clusterIP. Emp service will internally map and communicate to mongodb service.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes enables inter service communication by allowing services communicate with other services using their service name.

In your scenario, redis service should be accessible from other services on
http://app-api-redis-svc.default:6379. Here default is the namespace under which your service is running.

This internally routes your requests to your redis pod running on the target container port

Checkout this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/) for different modes of service discovery options provided by kubernetes

Hope it helps